# Load two scenes at the same time at runtime

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I have two scenes. One with a map and one with Buttons and stuff. *(A little bit like a UI scene)* How can I load the two scenes at the same time at run-time via script?

I think I need something like [`Application.LoadLevelAdditive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAdditive.html) but it's obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SceneManager.LoadScene` is what you are looking for. It has 3 overloads:

```
LoadScene(int sceneBuildIndex);
LoadScene(string sceneName);
LoadScene(int sceneBuildIndex, LoadSceneMode mode);
```

The last one is the answer to your question. You can specify the mode as additive.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
SceneManager.LoadScene(1,LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```